# CryptoJS extra parameter in AES Encrypt. How to replicate with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to replicate the following CryptoJS 3.1.2 code with PHP 5.4.4 :

```
var plaintext = 'test';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('9rIY8vV8DdOKx3m6JocjEaObhhYc2NfY');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('r0dkbnVQhklNeUGA');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M', key,{iv: iv,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
```

I have found several questions dealing with that problem, but none of them had that extra parameter in `encrypt()` between `plaintext` and `key`.

The CryptoJS wiki does not mention this parameter at all.
And yet, it works. I can decrypt with this :

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M', key, {iv: iv});
```

If I omit `'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M'` in the `decrypt()` call, it won't work.
So that parameter really does something. But what? Is is a hash, a salt?

Does anybody know how I can replicate this specific encryption process with PHP?

I can not modify this JS code in any way.
The code is on a login page and is used to encrypt credentials before they are sent to the server.

I am trying to use PHP-cURL to submit credentials to that server from the command line, which is why I need to reproduce this encryption process.

**Update: thanks to Jim's answer, I now have the proper JavaScript, now I need help with replicating the code in PHP**

Here is the JS :

```
var plaintext = 'test';
var key = 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M';
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('r0dkbnVQhklNeUGA');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, key,{iv: iv,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7})
```

`encrypted` equals `U2FsdGVkX1+ZujoXKqDHcO+4N1QO+Nv1KHUMFjZos1s=`

Here is the decryption:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
```

`decrypted` equals `test`

I have tried many different ways to replicate the encryption with PHP, but none of them gives a a string I can decode with the above JS.

For instance, using [this AES_Encryption class](http://www.coderelic.com/2011/10/aes-256-encryption-with-php/), I tried the following code :

```
$key = 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M';
$iv =  'r0dkbnVQhklNeUGA';
$message = 'test';
$AES              = new AES_Encryption($key, $iv, PKCS7);
$encrypted        = $AES->encrypt($message);
$decrypted        = $AES->decrypt($encrypted);
$base64_encrypted = base64_encode('Salted__'.$encrypted);
```

I end up with `U2FsdGVkX18eEv+TnigBEKGJL8t/V1Hm` instead of `U2FsdGVkX1+ZujoXKqDHcO+4N1QO+Nv1KHUMFjZos1s=`
Note that both strings start the same way, thanks to the 'Salted__' prefix I added (since CryptoJS seems to do the same thing).

I tried similar code with phpseclib, openssl_encrypt and mcrypt. No luck.

Any hint would be appreciated.

**Update: FIXED **

This PHP code is a perfect match for the CryptoJS code above.

```
function ssl_encrypt($pass, $data)
{
    // Set a random salt
    $salt = substr(md5(mt_rand(), true), 8);

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $block - (strlen($data) % $block);

    $data = $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    // Setup encryption parameters
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");

    $key_len =  mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
    $iv_len =  mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);

    $total_len = $key_len + $iv_len;
    $salted = '';
    $dx = '';
    // Salt the key and iv
    while (strlen($salted) < $total_len) {
        $dx = md5($dx.$pass.$salt, true);
        $salted .= $dx;
    }
    $key = substr($salted,0,$key_len);
    $iv = substr($salted,$key_len,$iv_len);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    //return chunk_split(base64_encode('Salted__' . $salt . $encrypted_data),32,"\r\n");
    return base64_encode('Salted__' . $salt . $encrypted_data);
}

function ssl_decrypt($password, $edata)
{
    $data = base64_decode($edata);
    print "Data: " . $data . "\n";

    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    print "Salt (Base64): " . base64_encode($salt) . "\n";

    $ct = substr($data, 16);
    print "Content (Base64): " . base64_encode($ct) . "\n";

    $rounds = 3;
    $data00 = $password.$salt;

    print "Data00 (Base64): " . base64_encode($data00) . "\n";

    $md5_hash = array();
    $md5_hash[0] = md5($data00, true);

    $result = $md5_hash[0];
    print "MD5-Hash[0] (Base64): " . base64_encode($result) . "\n";
    for ($i = 1; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
        $md5_hash[$i] = md5($md5_hash[$i - 1].$data00, true);
        $result .= $md5_hash[$i];
        print "Result (Base64): " . base64_encode($result) . "\n";
    }

    $key = substr($result, 0, 32);
    print "Key (Base64): " . base64_encode($key) . "\n";
    $iv = substr($result, 32, 16);
    print "IV (Base64): " . base64_encode($iv) . "\n";

    print "Decrypted: " . openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv) . "\n";
}

$encryptedString = ssl_encrypt('euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M', 'test');
$decryptedString = ssl_decrypt('euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M', $encryptedString);
```

I can't remember where I found it. Sorry.

Comment: You may use the \` character to indicate inline code  fragments.

Comment: To match PHP, you can't use a string for the key -- you have to use a word array. Try var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M'). Otherwise CryptJS is deriving a key as if from a passphrase. Also, PHP Mcrypt uses ZERO padding by default, so you might also need CryptJS.pad.ZeroPadding.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot change the JS. Whoever created it decided to use a string for the key (since the key paramater will be ignored, like you said earlier).

Answer (score 4):

This is a JavaScript thing, not a CryptoJS thing. Try this:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M', {iv: iv});
```

or this:

```
key = 'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M';
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {iv: iv});
```

You'll see that what you think is the key, isn't the key at all. It's being grouped with the optional parameters at the end, and lost.

'euhe68vjdr1aX4F091c7aCggSMBf0A7M' is your key, or is what your key is derived from.